# Difficulties with Count in query builder Laravel

Tags: laravel, count

Hello  i am trying to connect 4 of my tables to get all the necessary info in a view  The 4 tables are (i will only put the fields it matter for this case):

Users:
ID,
name

Mentoria (ID_mentor is the foreign key of users.id):
ID,
ID_mentor

Sessao_Mentoria:
ID,
ID_Mentoria

User_Sessao  (this is a pivot table that connects users and Sessao_mentoria tables, so ID_mentorando here is a foreign key to user.id  and id_sessao is a foreign key to sessao_mentoria.id):
ID_Mentorando,
ID_Sessao

Using this query i get the almost all the result i desire

```
   $sessoes= DB::table('sessao_mentoria')
                ->join('user_sessao', 'user_sessao.id_sessao', '=', 
                'sessao_mentoria.id')
                ->join('mentoria','mentoria.id', '=', 'sessao_mentoria.id_mentoria')
                ->join('users','users.id', '=', 'mentoria.id_mentor')
                ->select('sessao_mentoria.*','users.name')
                ->where('user_sessao.id_mentorando',$user->id)
                ->orderBy('sessao_mentoria.data')
                ->get();
```

I can get all data that is in «Sessao_mentoria table»,  and the identity of the «Mentor» that is connected to each «Sessao_mentoria), and put it in the order by «data»

However i also want to get how many  «mentorandos are connected to each «Sessao_mentoria», so my plan was adding a count in the «user_sessao» table, that would get me the number of «mentorandos» in each Sessao.  I tried doing like this

```
    $sessoes= DB::table('sessao_mentoria')
                ->join('user_sessao', 'user_sessao.id_sessao', '=', 
                   'sessao_mentoria.id')
                ->join('mentoria','mentoria.id', '=', 'sessao_mentoria.id_mentoria')
                ->join('users','users.id', '=', 'mentoria.id_mentor')
                ->select('sessao_mentoria.*','users.name', DB::raw('count(*) as sessao_count, 
                  user_sessao.id_mentorando'))
                ->where('user_sessao.id_mentorando',$user->id)
                ->groupBy('user_sessao.id_mentorando')
                ->orderBy('sessao_mentoria.data')
                ->get();
```

and it is only giving me the data of the first row of the Sessao_Mentoria table,  and it gives-me as the sessao_count result, the total number of «mentorandos» connected to any Sessao_mentoria, instead of the total number connected to each Sessao.  I also tried using Id_sessao, instead of Id_mentorando  in the count, and it gave me the same result,  so how can i solve this problem?  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone made a comment but erased it , however i was able to check it in time,  and i did what was suggested and i changed my group by,  to «Sessao_mentoria.id»  and it worked!
So thank you!